# Calculation error with pow operator

Tags: python

What should `print (-2 ** 2)` return? According to my calculations it should be `4`, but interpreter returns `-4`.
Is this Python's thing or my math is that terrible?

Comment: You should do (-2)**2 instead

Comment: The `-` has lower priority than `**`. This is interpreted as -(2**2), not (-2)**2...

Comment: The main reason this confuses most people is that they expect `-2` to be a literal meaning "negative 2", not an expression meaning "apply the negation operator to the literal 2 at runtime". Once you understand that it's an operator, the fact that it's a precedence issue is obvious; until you do, it's baffling. (That's why all the people who run into this are confused by `-2 ** 2`, not `-x ** 2`.)

Comment: in math -x² is a negative number or zero because power has higher precedence. So is `-2²` which is negative. Python is right

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), `**` has higher precedence than `-`, thus your code is equivalent to `-(2 ** 2)`. To get the desired result you could put `-2` into parentheses

```
>>> (-2) ** 2
4
```

or use built-in [`pow` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

```
>>> pow(-2, 2)
4
```

or [`math.pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow) function (returning `float` value)

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(-2, 2)
4.0
```

Answer (score 6):

The `**` operation is done before the minus. To get the results expected, you should do

```
print ((-2) ** 2)
```

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator):

> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): `-1**2` results in `-1`.

A full [detail of operators precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) is also available in the documentation. You can see the last line is `(expr)` which force the expr to be evaluated before being used, hence the result of `(-2) ** 2 = 4`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use math library...

```
math.pow(-2,2) --> 4
-math.pow(2,2) --> -4
math.pow(4,0.5) --> 2
```

Answer (score -2):

Python has a problem and does not see the -2 as a number. This seems to be by design as it is mentioned in the docs.

-2 is interpreted as -(2) {unary minus to positive number 2}

That usually doesn't give a problem but in -a ** 2 the ** has higher priority as - and so with - interpreted as a unary operatoe instead of part of the number -2 ** 2 evaluates to -2 instead of 2.

Comment: It's not Python's problem. This is how math works.