# print(a ** b ** c) - wrong precedence order - Python

Tags: python, function, double, exponential, operator-precedence

I tried to print(2 ** 3 ** 2) to test precedence order, but in Python then Python returned me 512.0 as result. I expected  Python would take 2 first, then to the power 3 = 8. Then 8, to the power 2 returning 64 as result (since operations are read from left to the right).

But instead, Python read 2 ** 3 ** 2 = 2 ** 9 = 512 (from right to the left).

Could someone explain why did this happen?

Comment: mathematically powers are evaluated from right to left.

Comment: Executing 2**3**2, or 2^3^2, or whatever the power syntax is for a language, is a great way to tell whether the language treats exponentiation at right or left associative.  As Danial said, right-associative of the standard in math.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759202/calculation-error-with-pow-operator

Answer (score 3):

It is described to behave that way [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator)

> The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> power ::=  ( await_expr | primary ) ["**" u_expr]
> ```
>
> Thus, **in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left** (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): `-1**2` results in `-1`.

To be pedantic your question is not about *precedence* in this case, but rather *associativity*.