# Different results for same mathematical operations

Tags: python

I encountered a strange behaviour in simple Python operations. It happens with power operation with two specific numbers:

```
print(-0.5660330877786267 ** 0.5515471713326932)
a = -0.5660330877786267
b = 0.5515471713326932
print(a ** b)
```

The outputs are unexpectingly not the same:

```
-0.7306015753489663
(-0.117797331106763+0.7210426136411876j)
```

Dose someone have an idea why this happens?

This happens with Python 3.8.1 on Windows. I tried both `**` operator and `pow` function.

[image]

Comment: Because `-x**y` is different from `(-x)**y`

Comment: The power operator has higher precedence than the unary minus operator, so they're **not** the same expression.

Comment: Yes, of course. How didn't I see that... Thanks!

Comment: Canonical duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759202/calculation-error-with-pow-operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because

```
print(-0.5660330877786267 ** 0.5515471713326932)
```

is actually

```
print(-(0.5660330877786267 ** 0.5515471713326932))
```

You can learn about operator precedence in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: Whereas `a ** b` is actually `(-0.5660330877786267) ** (0.5515471713326932)`

Answer (score 1):

`-0.5660330877786267 ** 0.5515471713326932` is **not** equivalent to `(-0.5660330877786267) ** (0.5515471713326932)`. Because of the relevant [precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator), it is equivalent to `-(0.5660330877786267 ** 0.5515471713326932)`, which of course has a different result.

With the `pow` function call, of course, the arguments are necessarily evaluated before the function is called, so it doesn't matter whether the values come from variables or literals.