# Why -1**0 = -1 in python?

Tags: python, math

Why does this code in python return -1 instead of 1?

```
-1**0
```

I have checked it in several versions of python, but still nothing.

Comment: Because it's `-(1 ** 0)`, not `(-1) ** 0`. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence, `**` binds more tightly than unary (or binary, for that matter) `-`.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23759202/3001761

Comment: @stefan_mit_hannover No. Anything to the zero power is `1`

Comment: Because [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try the `math.pow` function

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(-1, 0)
1.0
```

Or correctly group the operators; [exponents happen before negation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

```
>>> (-1) ** 0
1
```

Answer (score 0):

the hint is in the ast expansion:

```
$ pip install astpretty
...
$ astpretty t.py --no-show-offsets
Module(
    body=[
        Expr(
            value=UnaryOp(
                op=USub(),
                operand=BinOp(
                    left=Constant(value=1, kind=None),
                    op=Pow(),
                    right=Constant(value=0, kind=None),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
    type_ignores=[],
)
```

`-1**0` is best interpreted as `- (1 ** 0)` -- applying a unary negation to a power